# Mount to local directory without Fuse.

Tags: linux, ftp, vps, mount, fuse

I can not mount an FTP server using Fuse on my VPS because it does not support Fuse.
I think it's disabled in the kernel for security reasons.

So my question is: Is there a way to "point" a directory to FTP/WebDav server without the use of Fuse?

Answer (score 1):

In short, no. If your host wont enable FUSE or any other kernel module that allows you to mount filesystems in user space, then there's nothing you can run yourself. Your best bet is to check if your VPS has a module installed specifically for FTP filesystems, or get the host to install one, or get the host to enable FUSE.. or just move on to a different host.